# Magento DB : sales_flat_quote_item_option table has value column, how to get its value?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Actually I was exploring the tables required for addToCart feature. Just came across this 'value' column in sales_flat_quote_item_option, it has some json value but not sure from where its getting populated and what all value it holds. For eg. `'a:4:{s:4:\"uenc\";s:124:\"aHR0cDovL21hZ2VudG8tMS42LjAuMC1yYzIubG9jYWwvaW5kZXgucGhwL2VsZWN0cm9uaWNzL2NlbGwtcGhvbmVzL2JsYWNrYmVycnktODEwMC1wZWFybC5odG1s\";s:7:\"product\";s:2:\"17\";s:15:\"related_product\";s:0:\"\";s:3:\"qty\";s:1:\"1\";}'` .

Can somebody explain the values json holds ? Like what is 'uenc','s:124' etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need unserialize($str) with it. It return a array.